# Cloning text field without value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm cloning a row with a input field with JavaScript. My problem is I'm getting the value from my database, and now it's cloning the value as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clonedRow = $('.row3').clone().html();
    var appendRow = '<tr class = "row3">' + clonedRow + '</tr>';
    $('#btnAddMore').click(function() {
        $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
    });
});
```

Is there maybe a way I can get it to not clone the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var clonedRow = $('.row3').clone().html();
var appendRow = '<tr class = "row3">' + clonedRow + '</tr>';

$('#btnAddMore').click(function() {  
    $(appendRow).insertAfter('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').find('input').val('')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qr4Ft/2/)

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me. I tried the way you said but it's not working, if you check your fiddle it only clones one row and if you press the button again it doesn't clone again.

Comment: @user2130712 my bad!! fixed

Comment: Thanks it works, do you maybe know how I would do this to uncheck a radio button?